# How to display time in HH:MM format?

Tags: sql-server

How to display a time `HH:MM` format?

Using SQL 2000

In my Database time column datatype is `varchar`

Example

Table1

```
Time

08:00:00
09:00:23
214:23:32
```

Here I want to take only `08:00`, `09:00`, `214:23`

How to make a query for this condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Andrew was onto a correct solution, just didn't address all of the possibilities:

```
SELECT LEFT(Time, LEN(TIME)-3)
```

should trim off the last 3 characters.

Now, if you want to round up, that's another story....

Comment: Quesiton got altered after solution posted :/

Comment: @Andrew: question didn't get *altered*. Subject was changed to better correspond the body of the question.

Comment: OP altered it an added 214:23:32 case to the list. You subsequently altered the OP subject for clarity. It is of no consequence now.

Comment: @Andrew Sorry about that; didn't mean to swoop in on you.

Comment: Not a problem, no offence intended or taken. :)

Answer (score 2):

Whilst you could choose to turn the varchar into a datetime and format it there, assuming you do not want rounding, you could could shortcut the process. (Assuming the time format in the varchar is consistent)

```
select left('08:00:00',5)
```

Edit : Question altered, now I would use

```
select substring('243:00:00', 1, len('243:00:00') - 3)
```

and replace the value I used with the appropriate field

Cheap and cheerful.

Comment: That wasn't in the original question but i've altered the string work you have to do. working out the basic string manipulation isn't tough work.