# Formatting the time hh:mm:ss.0000000 to hh:mm not working

Tags: php, sql-server, date

I am using MsSQL  in PHP. I am storing the `time` in database table row with `datetime` as datatype.The time is stored like this :`08:30:00.0000000`.I need the time to be displayed in `08:30`.I have used

```
date('h:i', $time_value); // $time_value stores the time value
```

This formats the date and gives the result in 4:00. Any formatting is required to display the correct time stored in database?

Comment: you can refer this question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363647/trouble-using-mssql-datetime-in-php-via-sqlsrv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP [`date`](http://php.net/date) function does not expect a  [Mysql `datetime`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html) as second parameter but you do so:

```
date('h:i', $time_value);
                 ^
                 |
          second parameter
```

This is the reason why it does not work. You're using the wrong value, convert the database value into a timestamp first because the date function needs a timestamp. As you migh imagine, this has been done before, here is just a selection of related Q&A material:

- [MySQL convert datetime to unixtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18494493/367456)
- [MySQL convert datetime to Unix timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11133760/367456)

Alternatively just use a string function like [`substr`](http://php.net/substr) to obtain the string you're looking for:

```
$time_value = '08:30:00.0000000';
echo substr($time_value, 0, 5); # 08:30
```

Demo: https://eval.in/146148

You can do the conversion / formatting with the SQL statement already, a related example is given in:

- [How to display time in HH:MM format?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1524867/367456)

Comment: Fix the problem at the first place possible, here, select the data in the format you need it from the database already. If you share the SQL code you're using (at least in excerpt), I could have given more speaking example codes in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
date('h:i', strtotime('08:30:00.0000000'));
```

In your case:

```
date('h:i', strtotime($time_value));
```